# RPIO not working on Pi Zero, Pi2, or Pi3

Tags: python, rpio

How do you use RPIO on a Pi Zero, Pi2, or Pi3?

When I run an RPIO script I get a Python error message such as

`RuntimeError: rpio-pwm: Page 0 not present (pfn 0xa100000000015bba)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard release of RPIO does not support the Pi Zero, Pi2, or Pi3.

You will need to build RPIO from the github of RPIO version 2.

https://github.com/metachris/RPIO/tree/v2

Go to **that** github choose "Clone or download" and select "**Download ZIP**".

Then do the following on the Pi where you saved the ZIP.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev
unzip RPIO-2.zip
cd RPIO-2/
sudo python setup.py install
sudo python3 setup.py install
```